# Can someone explain this function in postresql?Here no join used then how using multiple tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.usp_get_licensedetail_report(
    from_date date,
    to_date date,
    district_code1 character varying,
    service_code1 integer,
    license_grade1 character varying)
    RETURNS TABLE(ack_no character varying, generate_list_no character varying, applicant_name_eng character varying, mobile_no character varying, firm_name_eng character varying, block_name character varying, district_name_eng character varying, license_no character varying, address text, service_name character varying, pincode character varying, license_valid_upto text) 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
    ROWS 1000
AS $BODY$
DECLARE p_license_grade character varying(50);
 begin

IF service_code1 in(1,2,25) THEN
        IF(license_grade1 = 'A') THEN
           p_license_grade = 'SG,C1,C2,C3';
        ELSE
           p_license_grade = license_grade1;
        END IF;
    ELSIF service_code1 in(6,7,28,10,11,30,14,15,27) THEN
        IF(license_grade1 = 'A')THEN
        p_license_grade = 'G1,G2';
        ELSE
            p_license_grade = license_grade1;
        END IF;
    ELSIF service_code1 in(18,19,29) THEN
        IF(license_grade1 = 'A')THEN
        p_license_grade = 'HV,EHV';
        ELSE
            p_license_grade = license_grade1;
        END IF;
    END IF;    

      RETURN query SELECT l.ack_no,l.generate_list_no,l.applicant_name_eng,l.mobile_no,l.firm_name_eng,b.block_name_eng as block_name,d.district_name_eng,s.license_no,
               CASE when l.service_code=1 or l.service_code=2 or l.service_code=18 or l.service_code=19  then l.firm_add_houseno || ',' || l.firm_add_locality || ','   || l.firm_add_landmark || ','  || l.firm_add_cityvillage || ','  || l.firm_add_roadstreet || ','  || b.block_name_eng   
               ELSE l.address_building || ','  || l.address_cityvillage || ','  || l.address_locality || ','  || l.address_landmark  || ','  || l.address_street || block_name_eng  end address,m.service_name,
               CASE when l.service_code=1 or l.service_code=2 or l.service_code=18 or l.service_code=19 then l.firm_pincode else l.pincode end pincode, to_char(s.license_valid_upto,'dd/MM/yyyy')as license_valid_upto
               FROM application_license l, districts d, blocks b, mst_license s, mst_services m  
               WHERE case when l.service_code in(1,2,18,19) then  l.firm_district else
               l.district_code end = d.district_code  and case when l.service_code in(1,2,18,19) then l.firm_taluk else l.taluk_code end= b.block_code and
               l.ack_no=s.ack_no and m.service_code=l.service_code and cast(l.ack_dt as date) between from_date and to_date and l.service_code=service_code1 and
               case when l.service_code in (19, 18, 1, 25, 29, 2) then l.firm_district else l.district_code end=district_code1 and
               l.license_grade in ( SELECT lic_grade FROM  REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE(p_license_grade, ',') as lic_grade ) and
               l.generate_list_no <>'' order by generate_list_no,applicant_name_eng;

End;

$BODY$;
```

In the above code no join used like left join or inner join, then how used multiple tables and can someone guess what might be this **REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE** , there is no table named like this in tables, and views then what might be this....help me out guys

Comment: p_license_grade is string that contains string which separates value by comma, REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE  splits them in to single column values, and l.license_grade has values that are looked into it.

Comment: `FROM application_license l, districts d, blocks b, mst_license s, mst_services m ` Old style. Kill it with fire.

Answer (score 0):

There **are** joins.  They are just `CROSS JOIN`s represented using the archaic comma notation.

The `WHERE` clause is just filtering these down to `INNER JOIN`s, making the query all the more confusing.

The `FROM` clause should really be written using proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax:

```
FROM application_license l JOIN
     districts d
     ON (case when case when l.service_code in(1,2,18,19) then  l.firm_district else l.district_code end) = d.district_code end JOIN
     blocks b
     ON (case when l.service_code in(1,2,18,19) then l.firm_taluk else l.taluk_code end) = b.block_code JOIN
     mst_license s
     ON l.ack_no = s.ack_no JOIN
     mst_services m 
     ON m.service_code = l.service_code
```

(I wouldn't have `CASE` expressions in the `ON` **or** `WHERE` clauses.)

And the `WHERE` clause as:

```
WHERE cast(l.ack_dt as date) between from_date and to_date and
      l.service_code = service_code1
```